# Audio progress event not called

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, html5-audio

So I have got this function in a class based component that loads an audio file from an api call

```
loadAudio = () => {
        var x = new Audio("http://localhost:5000/getSong")
        x.addEventListener("progress", event => { console.log("progress"); })
        this.setState({ audioSrc: x })
    }
```

I am calling this function from the componentDidMount function.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAudio()
}
```

The audio loads and I am able to play it using `.play()` but the `progress` event shows up only twice whereas the file is buffered multiple times when I hit the URL using a browser and use a similar script in vanilla JS. Then the `progress` is called multiple times.

I need to know the value of the audio that is loaded so I can hook it up with a buffering progressbar like any major streaming site has.

**Backend Script for reference:**

```
app.get('/getSong', cors(), function (req, res) {
    var path = require('path')
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname,"assets","b.mp3")
    console.log(filePath)

    var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });
    readStream.pipe(res)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```